# Google play services bug report

Tags: android, google-play-services

Where can I submit a bug report for Google Play services? I tried to search but I didn't find anything specific. The only site I found is official Android tracker but it doesn't seem to be the right place.

Comment: BTW: which bug you want to report?

Comment: have you already tried here? https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/

Comment: I saw but it seems related with Google play games.

Answer (score 0):

Issues for Play Services / Play Games project:
https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/list

Comment: That's only for Play Game Services Android sample apps, not Google Play Services. [ref](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/137#issuecomment-94857073)